# R: Checking variable types

Tags: r

I'm quite new to R, and I am currently trying to write a code with some foolproofing.

For example, I have a function where let's say it takes (n,c,l)
where the variables are supposed to be numerical, character, and logical types.

Is there a way so that I can check these things?
for example, I've tried `is.integer(3)` ... this returns FALSE.

Ideally, what I'm looking for is for example, suppose abc() is some function that will test if l==T or l==F (checking if the proper logical is input.
then: abc(T)  gives TRUE, and  abc(2) gives FALSE.

Also is there a way to check if n is specifically an integer? I mean I could check if (n%%1==0), but is there a specific function for this?

Thank you kindly in advance for what may seem to be a very basic question.

Comment: Compare `is.integer(3)` and `is.integer(3L)`.

Comment: 3 is not an integer, it's a double.  In R, 3L is the integer representation of 3.  You can use `is.numeric()`, as it returns TRUE for both integer and double, since both are numeric.

Comment: @RichardScriven and Pascal
thanks, I'll need to look into these differences then. Thanks for the heads up about "double", it was hidden in my memory back from when I learned C.
is.logical works as intended, as does is.character. I'll just use my modulus trick for the decimal check.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in the comments, you can use

```
is.numeric(3)#check whether numeric
is.integer(3L)#check whether integer
is.logical(TRUE)#Check whether logical
is.logical(2)#will return false
is.character("abc")#check whether character
is.character(4)#will return false
```

Similarly, you can check for other data types in R. Hope this is of help.

Comment: If we're being pedantic, don't use `T`, use `TRUE`

Comment: @thelatemail  Not pedantic. This is an important point often forgotten.

Comment: @KumarManglam Thank you for your answer, unfortunately my reputation from other stacks didn't carry over, so I won't be able to upvote anyone's answers for the time being.